# Best free web hosting for apple push notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm going to develop an iPhone app that use Apple push notification. Do you know a free web hosting that can permit it (SSL, etc)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at Linode (linode.com)

Comment: I don't see free plan on it, is correct?

Comment: Yeah don't think there is a free plan. Sorry didn't notice that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have choice of,

- Building your own APN sending script
  on the server
- Use [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)..

The positives of doing it yourself are that you get unlimited for free and probably have more control (although a push notification is a push notification is a push notification... how much control do you really need).

The positives of urban airship are that you save time/effort/resources. You don't have to maintain anything or fix any bugs.

Comment: Thanks guy but my problem is that I don't find a free web hosting where push notification works, some have the interest port blocked, some have the ssl off, etc... :/